# C# Amazon SQS to Java Amazon SQS

Tags: c#, java, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have been tasked with converting a function that utilizes AmazonSQS from Java to C#. In the function I was given a line similar to this appears twice

```
// x is a Message that is passed in as a parameter

Amazon.SQS.Model.Attribute sentTimestampx = x.Attribute.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name == "SentTimestamp");
```

I am unsure what this line is doing specifically, but I think it is searching the SQS Message for a label/attribute called "SentTimestamp" and storing this value in sentTimestampx.

I have attempted to find an equivalent function in Java but have so far been unable to do so. 
In Java the AmazonSQS Message has a function called getAttributes() but this returns a Map which I am unsure how to deal with.

Can I please get some clarification as to what the c# line is actually doing, and how I would use the Map returned by the getAttributes() method in Java to simulate the functionality?

Answer (score 0):

It should be equivalent to:

```
Amazon.SQS.Model.Attribute sentTimestampx = null;

for (Amazon.SQS.Model.Attribute a : x.getAttributes())
{
    if (a.Name == "SentTimestamp")
    {
        if (sentTimestampx == null)
        {
            sentTimestampx = a;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Boooooh! there is more than one matching elements!");
        }
    }
}
```

I think that a good approximation is to remove the check for more than one matching element and break the loop when you've found one, unless the original intent was really to throw an exception.